# Executing the following steps in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Here are the steps I am doing again and again, and I was wondering if I can write a script which does this.

I have two local accounts:

1. thrust
2. hduser

Now, I am writing Java code in Eclipse in my `thrust` account.
After the code runs satisfactorily, I do:

```
mvn clean
cp -r /home/thrust/projectA -r /tmp/
su - hduser
cp -r /tmp/projectA /home/hduser/
cd /home/hduser/projectA
mvn package
```

Is there a way I can automate all these steps?

Or is there a way I can write code on this `thrust` account and the code automatically syncs with the `hduser` account?

Comment: Yes, there is. Do a Google search for "bash scripting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are writing code (and you are doing it "again and again"), it seems you should be using a revision control system (like Subversion or Git), either with a local repository or with a hosting service (for example: GitHub or Bitbucket).

If you don't want to use an RCS, you can create a shell script to automate what you are already doing, as suggested by @iamnotmaynard.

Also, take a look at `rsync` or `ssh`. They can help you to copy files from one user to another more easily (`rsync` can also help you to keep these files synchronized).